# (complex?) LINQtoSQL query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables: Designs and Urls.  A Design can be related to many URLs through a Guid (which is not the primary key of the Design table, as a URL can be related to other tables as well through the same column).

```
Design (table)
-------
DesignGuid

URL (table)
------
RelationalGuid
UrlString
```

In my code I am trying to determine if some information that I am given requires the creation of a new Design record, or if it corresponds to an existing Design record.  The information includes a list of URLs.  These URLs are the only way to determine whether or not a new record needs to be created or not.

`var localUrlStrings = new List<string>() { "urlString1", "urlString2" }`

So, I need to take a list of URLs that I am given and write a query that looks at existing Design records and their associated URLs and return a match IFF the URLs match exactly.  So, if I'm given 2 URLs in my code, I need to find only those Designs (should be either 1 or 0 matches) that are associated to exactly 2 URLs that match the 2 I have in code exactly.

Thanks,
Jeromeyers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you want a SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT d.DesignGuid
FROM Design AS d
INNER JOIN URL as u ON d.DesignGuid = u.RelationalGuid
WHERE u.UrlString IN ('urlstring1', 'urlstring2', ... ,'urlstringn')
```

I think something like this should work:

```
var localUrlStrings = new List<string>() { "urlString1", "urlString2" }

var result = 
    from d in Design
    from u in URL
    where d.DesignGuid == u.RelationalGuid
    && localUrlStrings.Contains(u.UrlString)
    select new {
        d.DesignGuid,
        u.UrlString
    });
```

**Edit: You're looking for this:**

```
SELECT d.DesignGuid, count(u.URL) as numURLs
FROM Design as d,
     Url as u
WHERE d.DesignGuid = u.RelationalGuid
HAVING count(u.URL) = 2
```

I can't test it right now, but I believe this should do the trick (the syntax might be a little off, I'll double check it in the morning):

```
var result = 
    from d in dataContext.Designs
    join u in dataContext.URLs on d.DesignGuid equals u.RelationalGuid into joinTable
    from j in joinTable
    where localUrlStrings.Contains(j.UrlString)
    group j by j.RelationalGuid into groupTable
    where groupTable.Count() == localUrlStrings.Count
    select groupTable.Key;
```

Comment: That's what I've ended up using, essentially.  However, what I was looking for was a query that returned those DesignIDs that have exactly (in this case) 2 urls where those 2 urls exactly match the two in the list.  This returns DesignIDs (matched with their URL) where even a single of multiple URLs match at least one urlString in the list.  So, I've taken to using code to further narrow the list down to only those with exact matches both with count and with content.  I was hoping to do this all in a LinqToSql query without the necessity of code afterwards.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're doing there! I edited the solution with an (untested) updated solution..

Comment: Awesome!  I had to change a couple things.  Basically, you neglected to use the "localUrlStrings" List.  So, I added a "where localUrlStrings.Contains(u.UrlString)" before the group by statement and I substituted the ">=2" with "== localUrlStrings.Count".  And also, when you group by "j", "j" is from the Urls table, so you have to use "j.RelationalGuid" instead of "j.DesignGuid".  But in essence, your answer produced (in the case of a list with 2 URLs) a result with half the count of our previous solution (which is expected, since there are 2 Urls).  Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and edited your answer to take care of the couple of errors so that I could mark it as the answer.

Comment: Whoops - that's what happens when code tired and in notepad! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

try (not entirely sure about the exact result needed):

```
var Result = from d in Design from u in URL from l in localUrlStrings 
             where d.DesignGuid == u.RelationalGuid and 
             l == u.UrlString select new { l, d.DesignGuid };
```

Comment: I expected as much, but I gave it a try.  Local sequences cannot be used in this manner in LINQ to SQL queries.  I could do a urls.contains(u.UrlString)...  The exception message is:  "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."  This is a troublesome aspect of LinqToSql.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the Title to reflect LinqToSql constraint